# Why would a SELECT INTO cause an arithmetic overflow?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am doing this

```
SELECT * INTO table1 FROM Table0
```

I get an arithmetic overflow on a datetime column (error converting to smalldatetime), however the destinations schema that got created has a datetime column and not a smalldatetime column..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds to me like you have an implicit conversion to smalldatetime, probably in a computed column. If you look at the Estimated Execution Plan, you'll probably see Compute Scalar operations in there. Hit F4 to see the properties, and you should be able to see the calculations that are being done, including any implicit conversions that are being used.

Comment: Yes there was a computed column.. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problem is always indicative of corruption and can easily be debugged with

```
DBCC CHECKTABLE(<tablename>) WITH DATA_PURITY;
```

> [**DATA_PURITY**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174338.aspx)
>   Causes DBCC CHECKTABLE to check the table for column values that are not valid or out-of-range. For example, DBCC CHECKTABLE detects columns with date and time values that are larger than or less than the acceptable range for the datetime data type; or decimal or approximate-numeric data type columns with scale or precision values that are not valid.

Comment: Actually as was mentioned earlier, its a computed column that was causing the problem..

Comment: The fact that the computed column causes an overflow is technically a corruption, and can be detected by the check.

Comment: @RemusRusanu - Is this only for persisted computed columns? It doesn't report anything for `CREATE TABLE T(Id int, X AS CAST('Fish' AS INT));INSERT INTO T DEFAULT VALUES;SELECT * INTO #T FROM T;DBCC CHECKTABLE(T) WITH DATA_PURITY;`

Comment: @MartinSmith: you're right, data purity will only validate the storage format (ie persisted columns bits on disk). I was thrown aback by the very fact that you could create the computed column, obviously the DDL never evaluated the expression, but on second thought that is normal. Computed column usually depend on row data and during CREATE there are no rows, so it cannot be evaluated. During ALTER ... ADD... it could be evaluated, but there is no 'distinguished' row to try it on, so it would mean a size-of-data scan validation on all rows.

Comment: Think of it as a feature to catch unhealthy use of `SELECT *` :) `alter table t add [Thou Shall Not Use *] AS 1/0;`.